# How to prefer shorthand object return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

How can I tell ESLint that, when a function is just returning an object, it should use the shorthand? For example:

```
const someMethod = c => {
    return { c }
};
```

Should be:

```
const someMethod = c => ({ c });
```

Comment: Just some gentle pushback: The former is much easier to debug. Leave minifying to minifiers.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style

Comment: ESLint rules can be turned on and off for a reason. They depict a certain coding style preference, which you can agree on, or not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually he was right, it is a matter of configuring the rule

Comment: I like this rule on. Hate having extra unnecessary garbage in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to andy I found the right config:

```
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"]
```